# Determine which tables are locked

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have to following problem. I have an application where users can login and do some things like adding new item. I also have statistics in Reporting Services. The problem is that statistic is time consuming and when it is executed, users cannot make new items. In my sql query for statistic I have all select statements decorated by WITH nolock statement. However I can see some tables are locked using Activity Monitor. Is it correct that I see them in locked by objects tab? How can I figure out which tables are locked?
When I use the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WITH (nolock)
```

I can also see this query locks MyTable table. Please help me.

Comment: Not all locks are the same: Shared, Update , Exclusive

Comment: Do you have multiple tables in any of your statistics queries? If so, is each table `nolock` ed? e.g. `SELECT * FROM table1 WITH (nolock) INNER JOIN table2 WITH (nolock) ON ...`

Comment: yes...each of them has WITH (nolock)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use NOLOCK. [Dirty reads are inconsistent reads](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx).

Use instead [SNAPSHOT ISOLATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Then you get the best of both worlds: consistent reads *and* no locks. Remove all lock hints from your queries, then enable read committed snapshot:

```
ALTER DATABASE [<dbname>] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

Comment: Will it work if I set this before my statistic's query execution?

Comment: This is a database option. Once set, it will remain set. You need only do this once and that's it.

Comment: ok.but I want to SET it before query is executed and then restore default settings after query is executed

Comment: No. You set it and leave it set.